# Почему буква Ё не проходит регулярку?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Код:

```
preg_match('/^[а-я]+$/siu', $query)
```

Comment: потому что ее код не лежит в диапазоне между "а" и "я". так что явно добавьте ее в скобки

Comment: См. [таблицу Юникода](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0400-04FF), `ё` вторая буква после `я`, т.е. вне указанного вами диапазона. Кстати, модификатор `s` можно смело удалить из этого регулярного выражения.

Comment: @Mike Ответ-то напишите[.?]

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Мне из этого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%5D+%D1%91 очень сложно выбрать вопрос, которым этот можно закрыть по дублю. склоняюсь к ...

Comment: @Mike, на всё так однозначно. glibc, например: `$ echo '1аяё2' | sed 's/[а-я]//g'`, ожидаемый результат: `12`. т.е., это работа с юникодом в php (и java, судя по дубликату) реализована через это самое место.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin perl при этом придерживается того же представления о Ё как и php, java, ... Учитывая, что в стандарте описанном на unicode.org указано, что в интервалах используются именно code-point можно сказать что рассмотренные языки придерживаются этого стандарта, а posix видимо нет. возможно на его регулярные выражения у него есть свой стандарт. Кстати, `grep -E`, работает как sed, а `grep -P` как perl (и остальные), видимо потому что использует libpcre